# Upgrading Sharepoint 2010 CMP file to 2013

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, 2013

I have exported a team site from Sharepoint 2013 into a CMP file. However, when I try to run Import-SPWeb, I get the Version package is different.

I am looking for anyway possible to upgrade this cmp file to version 15 so I can Import it, or to upgrade the actual 2010 site to 2013 than do an import. I am unable to move the site using Move-SPSite because I have no test farm and the site currently resides in the Central Admin site.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify did the cmp come from SP2010 or SP2013? You can't export a site from 2010 and import into 2013.

Comment: Yes it is from 2010. So there is no other way than going through the upgrade process to get a SP 2010 Site onto 2013?

Comment: Out of the box, the only way to get content from SP2010 to SP2013 is a database attach upgrade. You could use third party migration tools for version to version upgrades of specific content.

Comment: Can you recommend any 3rd party tool? If not any help on upgrading the standard way would be appreciated. Again I don't have a test farm to play with.

Comment: Metalogix, AvePoint, Axceler, and Quest all make migration tools that will do what you need. Disclosure: I work for a company that has partnerships with Metalogix, AvePoint, and Axceler.

Comment: Any tool that is open source?

Answer (score 1):

Without the use of a migration tool, you need to upgrade the entire site collection to SharePoint 2013, and then export your team site to a .cmp file. It is a fairly straight forward process even if it is a lot of work just to move a team site to 2013.

In your case I would follow the guide [Upgrade a site collection to SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219650.aspx). The steps involved in this process are:

> - Run the site collection health checks to verify the site is ready to upgrade. For more information, see Run site collection health checks in SharePoint 2013.
> - Create an upgrade evaluation site to preview the differences between versions. (Optional)
> - Upgrade the site collection.
> - Verify that upgrade was successful and the site works as expected. For more information, see Review site collections upgraded to SharePoint 2013.

When all of this is done, you can easily continue with your task to export your team site in 2013 and import it to the real production site collection. It takes a while, but its done in a controlled manner.